# Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to UIScrollViews' UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm developing a Notification Center plugin, and I'm having trouble with UITapGestureRecognizer. I have a UIScrollView, With UIViews acting as a wrapper for my two UILabels in it.

The selector I attached to the UITapGestureRecognizer is never called, and I have no idea why.

**EDIT:** okay, now it works, but only for the last element in the UIScrollView. I guess it's because I'm using the same UILabel in the loop. What should I do?

```
- (UIView *)view
{
if (_view == nil)
{

    self.aArray = [self.connector refreshData];

    _view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 0, 316, 110)];

//setting the background 
    UIImage *bg = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/WeeAppPlugins/NCAppline.bundle/WeeAppBackground.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:10];
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
    bgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 316, 110);
    [_view addSubview:bgView];

//creating the scrollview
    UIScrollView *scrView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *linkTappedRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                 initWithTarget: self
                                 action: @selector(articleTap:)];
    linkTappedRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    linkTappedRec.enabled = YES;
    linkTappedRec.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;

//getting the number of pages required
    NSInteger viewcount = [self.aArray count]/3; 

    for (int i = 0; i <viewcount; i++) 
    { 
        CGFloat y = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

        UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 306, 23)];
        /* setting bunch of properties */

        UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 25, 288, 85)];
                    /* setting bunch of properties */

//this will be the container
        UIView *vview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(y, 0,                                                      self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [vview addSubview:lbl1];
        [vview addSubview:lbl2];
        vview.tag = i*3+2;

        [vview addGestureRecognizer:linkTappedRec];

        vview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [scrView addSubview:vview]; 
    }

    scrView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width *viewcount, self.view.frame.size.height);
    scrView.pagingEnabled = YES;


    [_view addSubview:scrView];  

}

return _view;
}

- (void)articleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog("tap");
}
```

Comment: it's not, because I would see it in the log. btw I added         scrView.canCancelContentTouches = YES; since then, but still nothing

Comment: yes, it's right there: `[vview addGestureRecognizer:linkTappedRec];`

Comment: what do you mean? Isn't this what gesture recognizers are for? But if I add the same recognizer to the scroll view, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Whatever you add the gesture recognizer to receives its selector. So if you want to do something with it you need to subclass the object and give it a method to be triggered by the selector. `UIScrollView`s are strange creatures also, they don't always play nice with gesture recognizers.

Comment: okay, now it works, but only for the last element in the UIScrollView. I guess it's because I'm using the same UILabel in the loop. What should I do?

Comment: Try this - don't use gesture recognizers. They kind of suck. This all looks like you could make it in interface builder, just use buttons. You can even make them invisible and place them beneath the labels. Otherwise it's pretty messy and a pain to debug. The less code you write, the better.

Comment: With buttons the UX kinda sucks. It takes a little more time for it to notice that it was pressed then for a tap gesture recognizer.

According to the UIGestureRecognizer class reference:

_action

    A selector that identifies the method implemented by the target to handle the gesture recognized by the receiver. The action selector must conform to the signature described in the class overview. NULL is not a valid value._

and since self is the target, using the method implemented there should be fine.

Comment: Then make a custom class for the thing you want to add the gesture recognizer to, and put the gesture recognizer code and method in it. Or make the main class the delegate of the custom class and use the delegate pattern to call methods from the class. If you want buttons to be more responsive, use the touch down event instead of the default touch up inside.